# Why the following code prints false?

Tags: java

can any one please explain me why the following code prints `false`

```
    public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(true?false:true == true?false:true);
}
}
```

Comment: this is actually `true?(false):(true == true?false:true)` I think you wanted `(true?false:true) == (true?false:true)`

Comment: what are you trying to make out of the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`true?false:true == true?false:true` is evaluated from left to right, so it's equivalent to `true?false:(true == true?false:true)`. Since `true` is `true`, the first ternary expression returns `false`, which is the printed output.

Answer (score 3):

Since the first condition is `true`, it will print `false`.

edit:

That is using the ternary operator, basically it is a simplified if.

```
       if (true) {
           System.out.println(false);
       } else {
           if (true == true) {
               System.out.println(false);
           } else {
               System.out.println(false);
           }
           System.out.println(true);
       }
```

using the ternary operator, this can be simplified as

```
System.out.println(true?false:true == true?false:true);
```

so the post above uses the same operation using true or false.

Comment: yeah i just saw I messed up, give me a sec I will change it to use the example from the question